# Why aren't my email messages being sent from my VPS using PhpList?

Tags: email, ubuntu, sendmail, vps, phplist

I have a VPS from Digital Ocean. I installed Phplist on my server. Digital Ocean has only provided me an IP adress. And i am trying to send emails directly from phpList by Browsing through that IP address? Is this the reason, that i am not being able to send email from it?

or Should i get a domain name like (example.com) to be able to send email? or there are more configurations to be done besides installing phpLst. I have installed Apache , mysql and php on that server and its running ubuntu 12.04 (32bit)..

Comment: Did you set a SMTP server? It's best to use the SMTP server of your hosting provider if they have one.

Comment: Is SMTP server required? Don't the sendmail works?

Comment: Is your configuration set correctly? http://docs.phplist.com/PhpListConfiguration.html#hn_Mail_server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a SMTP server in your VPS to send mails.
I prefer using postfix in your ubuntu server.
Try the following link. It might help you.
[**Install and Setup Postfix on Ubuntu**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-12-04)

After this open up your config.php file and search for the following line of code: 
`define("PHPMAILERHOST",'');` 
Replace **PHPMAILERHOST** with your server host name(example.com)